# Using adafruit_debouncer on a keyboard matrix

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

I am implementing a key matrix in Circuitpython on a Raspberry Pi Pico.

I have gotten to the point where I can scan and read fine. Now I need to add debouncing. I would like to use adafruit_debouncer for that.

First I fell for the mistake of simply debouncing the column input-pins with hilarious results as the debouncer tried to make sense of the values while the rows where being scanned...

Now I want to create a debouncer for each key and I think I should be able to use adafruit_debouncer by not giving it a DigitalIO-instance to work on but a lambda that looks at a specific cell in my two-dimensional array of key states.

Given two suitably sized 2D-arrays of keystates and debouncers I create them like this:

```
for rowindex in range(len(rowpins)):
    for colindex in range(len(colpins)):
        debouncers[rowindex][colindex] = adafruit_debouncer.Debouncer(lambda: keystates[rowindex][colindex])
```

After doing each scan that updates `keystates[][]`, putting in Trues and Falses according to wether a key is down or not, I then iterate over `debouncers[][]`, call `update()` on each and then query their `value`.

Unfortunately no debouncer seems to be able to see the `True` values from the array. At least none ever report a `True` themselves.

What is my mistake?